# unable to send email via cypress-email-result

Tags: smtp, cypress, nodemailer

I want to email the cypress test results programmatically preferably a single file for all spec files. I am using [cypress-email-results](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-email-results)
But the file  `cypress/plugins/index.js` is not running. I am checking this by console.log on first line

```
    console.log("inside plugin/index.js");
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: '**********@gmail.com',
      pass: '***********'
    }
  });



module.exports = (on, config) => {
    require('cypress-email-results')(on, config, {
      email: ['***********@gmail.com'],
      transporter
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cypress version 10 or greater, the plugins configuration has changed.

You now need to put them in the `cypress.config.js` which is at the root of the project.

The quickest way to test it out is to import your old `cypress/plugins/index.js` into the new file, like this

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config) // run old config
    },
    baseUrl: '...',
  },
})
```

If that works you can migrate the code from `cypress/plugins/index.js` to `setupNodeEvents()` one by one and run your tests in between each step.

It may be that not all plugins will migrate.

---

Looking at `cypress-email-results` package, it looks straight forward to upgrade.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

      require('cypress-email-results')(on, config, {
        email: ['user1@email.com', 'user2@email.com'],
      })
    },
    baseUrl: '...',
  },
})
```

---

**Nodemailer configuration**

According to the sample given in `cypress-email-results` repository, nodemailer is set up as follows

```js
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
// the settings could come from .env file or environment variables
const host = process.env.SMTP_HOST || 'localhost'
const port = Number(process.env.SMTP_PORT || 7777)

// create your own SMTP transport
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host,
  port,
  secure: port === 456,
})

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('cypress-email-results')(on, config, {
    email: ['user1@email.com', 'user2@email.com'],
    // pass your transport object
    transport,
  })
}
```

So inside `createTransport`, set up `host` and `port` instead of `service` and `auth`.

Comment: thanks for answer. But it is not accepting my transporter built via nodemailer using gsmtp.  Can help in this also. I had updated the question with my transporter or should I create a new question

Comment: I can take a look, but not sure if I can help.